# RoboSpice vs LoopJ library

Tags: android, android-networking

Ive been comparring the two libraries and they both seem to do exactly what i want, `robospice` looks to be a little more then what i want while `LoopJ` looks just right. But i wanted to get some solid feedback from someone who has used BOTH. Im coming over from iOS where i used `AFNetworking` as my networking library.

My app had a chat system, has a friendslist, its basically a basic social networking app with a special niche.

I did notice one thing so far as well. Its hard to find the documentation for RoboSpice, as well has it looks more complicated to setup because it has to have some other REST Library, god knows why it doesn't just give it its own...

Edit: Figured i would make this post a little more SEO friendly...

Whats the best Android Library to use for Networking, handling multiple threads on its own not interfering with my Main UI Threads. ect ect.

Comment: Downvoted? Wtf? show me a post just like to to justify your downvote. Or explain yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my library (advertising my stuff :) ) which i have been using for a long time now in all my android apps and the developers that work with me also use it. Takes care of the Async part:

https://github.com/darko1002001/android-rest-client

And i reccomend this one: (LoopJ)

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

It works great.

You probably won't need anything more that these offer.

Comment: When do you think you might support file upload? Your library looks real clean, simple and small i like it.

Comment: Thats pretty much the next thing i want to add. with some default parsers to save to file location from the response. There is room to process some additional stuff in the background thread as well before doing the actual request. i found it useful when needing to calculate md5 hashes or base64 from byte arrays. :) Glad you like it.